# Unity: Enemy Generation Code

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I almost got my game done. However, I want to generate infinite enemies, like in avoider games. However, I tried researching and no luck. How can I do this? It is the only thing I need to do to finish my game.

The BlockScript.cs code (The enemy code) is the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject wayPoint;
    private Vector3 wayPointPos;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody2D;
    public bool inGround = true;
    private float jumpForce = 400f;

    private float speed = 6.0f;
    void Start () {

        wayPoint = GameObject.Find("wayPoint");
    }

    private void awake()
    {
        rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void Update () {

        if (inGround)
        {
            inGround = false;

            rigidBody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
        }

        wayPointPos = new Vector3(wayPoint.transform.position.x, transform.position.y,
            wayPoint.transform.position.z);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            wayPointPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector2 min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));

        if(transform.position.y< min.y)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.
You can improve your question by formatting your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution would be to store your enemy (the complete hierarchy for a  `GameObject`) in a [prefab](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/prefabs-concept-usage) so that they can be re-used and instantiated from code. Then, create a reference to your prefab and instantiate it whenever you see fit. For example:

```
public GameObject EnemyPrefab; // assign this in editor
(...)
Instantiate(EnemyPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation); // creates a new enemy
```

You will probably need to control this functionality from a separate script, not from the enemy script itself (eg. create a specialized `EnemySpawner` script)

Comment: Pleasure to help!